# Problemas al cargar una pagina con parámetros con nodejs e incidencias al cargar el CSS

Tags: css, nodejs, express, parametros, ejs

Tengo un proyecto web, el cual lo estoy haciendo con nodejs, funciona todo correcto, pero al acceder a una pagina con parámetros, este de aquí me lanza un error y es que al querer obtener el código que viene en el parámetro, por alguna razón me toma el texto style.css, es decir, al momento en que el archivo css viaja al lado del cliente se queda en la variable que está especificada para almacenar el id que requiero, por ende me lanza un error al no poder tener un id comparable, además de que el archivo css no termina llegando del lado del cliente.

Cabe señalar que tengo especificados los archivos estaticos

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Y la ruta donde esta la lógica para obtener el id

```
router.get('/:subnivelId', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const subNivelId = req.params.subnivelId;
        const preguntas = await questionsController.getPreguntasPorSubnivel(subNivelId);
        res.render('questions', { user: req.user, preguntas });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al cargar datos para la página de preguntas:', error);
        res.render('questions', { user: req.user, preguntas: [] });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola Deither, ¿qué es lo que ves en la consola? ¿Te da algún error? Lo que comentas suena un poco raro y puede que no sea por el código compartido en la pregunta, ¿puedes añadir algo más de información? ¿estás usando el texto "style.css" en otra parte?

Comment: Sorry por tardar en dar respuesta, a la final "solucione" el error, o mejor dicho, busque otra alternativa a que funcionará, pues cabe señalar que uso nodejs y express para este proyecto y tengo mi carpeta public donde esta el style.css por que este nunca se llamaba correctamente y generaba un error lo que me impedía que la pagina cargará, a la final la solución fue no llamar el style.css si no que agregar la etiqueta <style> al html y agregarle todos los estilos necesarios para está pagina.

Answer (score 0):

### **ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Una disculpa por no expresarme bien en está pregunta tenía muchas malas noches acumuladas jasjajsjsa

En vista que quiero darle solución a este error, sobre todo porque quiero mejorar este proyecto universitario y agregarlo a mi portafolio. Estoy usando nodejs y express para el backend de este proyecto por lo que uso la clase Router para armar las rutas de esta app web.
Entonces, al configurar las rutas todo funciona de maravilla y el proyecto es navegable por medio de las rutas, las paginas cargan y todo normal, el problema llega cuando intento usar una ruta con parámetros.

```
router.get('/:subnivelId', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const subNivelId = req.params.subnivelId;
        const preguntas = await questionsController.getPreguntasPorSubnivel(subNivelId);
        res.render('questions', { user: req.user, preguntas });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al cargar datos para la página de preguntas:', error);
        res.render('questions', { user: req.user, preguntas: [] });
    }
});
```

Como se denota en el código, al acceder a dicha ruta, se debía capturar el parámetro que venía en la url para así llamar a una determinada función.

Es aquí donde se genera el error y hace que el servicio se termine cayendo y es que por alguna razón lo que estoy capturando de los parámetros no resulta ser un id o un valor numérico como se espera, si no que al contario, se esta obteniendo un tipo de dato que no podía ser procesado por la función, lo que generaba el crasheo del proyecto.

En un principio supuse que al obtener el parámetro de la url, este se estaría capturando como una cadena o algo así, lo que era fácil solucionar con convertir ese dato al tipo de dato deseado PEROOO es aquí el lío, al pesar de indicar en el código que se debía capturar el parámetro ***:id***, este no lo tomaba, si no que al contrario, por alguna razón terminaba tomando el archivo estático y de estilos (***style.css***), el cual lo señalo como estático en app.js de la siguiente forma

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Me percaté de este acontecimiento al mostrar por consola el supuesto id que se capturaba de la url pues en vez de mostrarme el código que venía en la dirección como parámetro, este me mostraba por consola el nombre del archivo.

```
>style.css
```

Es aquí donde todo se me hace muy confuso y no entiendo como el archivo estático termina desviando al parámetro de la url. Tal vez mi falta de conocimiento y experiencia me limita a conocer la generación de este fallo y es aquí donde me interesa aprender mas pero sin embargo no logro llegar a conseguir alguna respuesta y es por mi desesperación, cansancio y falta de sueño que termino haciendo la pregunta tan vaga y sin buena información por la que pido disculpa.

**SOLUCIÓN MOMENTÁNEA**

Mientras trataba averiguar la provocación de dicho error, probe diversas cosas, desde direccionar a la ubicación del archivo en la carpeta del proyecto, hasta eliminar la etiqueta ***link*** en el html donde indicaba el uso del archivo ***style.css*** para la generación de los estilos de la pagina. En esta prueba y error, y al eliminar la etiqueta ***link*** consigo que se deje de provocar el error y que se capture correctamente el parámetro ***:id*** PEROOOO es aquí otro inconveniente, pues obviamente al no tener la etiqueta para referencia el archivo css la pagina me carga sin estilo lo que hace que esta no sea la solución.

Lo único que se me ocurrió a partir de aquí es generar una etiqueta ***style*** dentro del html, donde escribiría todos los estilos necesarios para que ahora si cargará correctamente la pagina (en términos visuales) y así mismo se permita capturar el id de la url.

Si bien, esto se convirtió en una solución, en lo personal no me parece lo correcto en temas práctico. Y me he quedado con la espina de poder solucionar dicho error y que sea posible poder seguir usando el archivo estático css sin que se generé conflicto en la captura del id de la url.

**EL PROYECTO EN LA ACTUALIDAD**

Tras esta "solución" pude seguir desarrollando el proyecto sin problemas y cumplir con el plazo de entrega. Ahora que lo volví abrir y revisar para seguir desarrollando y mejorarlo, trate de volver a usar el archivo estático css y llamarlo desde el html

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Cabe señalar que de esa forma referencio el archivo de estilo en todos los html.

Ahora por alguna razón no se genera el error anteriormente mencionado y se puede capturar correctamente los parámetros id y digo los "parámetros", debido que al seguir desarrollando el proyecto me vi en la necesidad de actualizar la routa para está pagina, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
router.get('/:subnivelId/:numeroPregunta', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const subNivelId = req.params.subnivelId;
        const numeroPregunta = req.params.numeroPregunta;
        const generarHTMLPregunta = await questionsController.generarHTMLPregunta(req, res, subNivelId, numeroPregunta);
        res.render('questions', { user: req.user, generarHTMLPregunta });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al cargar datos para la página de preguntas:', error);
        res.render('questions', { user: req.user, generarHTMLPregunta: '' });
    }
});
```

Ahora resulta que no carga el archivo css al pesar que se encuentra referenciado con la etiqueta ***link***. Al revisar la herramienta de desarrolladores del navegador y revisar las fuentes que llegan al cliente, me encuentro que el archivo ***style.css*** llega del lado del cliente pero por alguna extraña razón en vez de contener toda la lógica para el estilo, este carga con la lógica del html...

Ahora mismo la cabeza me quiere explotar y no se si esto al final los haga confundir mas, pero creo que el error base se entiende.

Necesito su ayuda para que me guíen o me aconsejen en que estoy haciendo mal o cual es mi error, si sirve de algo quiero terminar señalando que estoy usando .ejs como html. Revisaré si es por el uso del .ejs que se esta generando este ultimo error, espero lograr encontrar respuesta y de ser así agregarla aquí por si le sirve a alguien. De antemano gracias por el tiempo y perdón el mucho texto.

Comment: No entiendo si esta es la respuesta al problema, o un nuevo problema.. si es un nuevo problema, hace una nueva pregunta y deja solo la respuesta a este problema aca... si no, nadie va a ver tu pregunta...